# Select data from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, pdo

Instead of writing 2 different queries, I'd like to do in one

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT      Car_Name
    FROM        Car_data
    WHERE       Car_Code = :carCode
    SELECT      Fruit_Name
    FROM        Fruit_Data
    WHERE       Fruit_Code = :fruitCode;
");
$query->bindParam(':carCode', $header['Car_Code']);
$query->bindParam(':fruitCode', $header['Fruit_Code']);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!empty($result)) {
}
```

I expect to receive data in the following format:

if both tables has data:

```
Car_Name = 'Golf'
Fruit_Name = 'Banana'
```

if only one table has data:

```
Car_Name = 'Golf'
Fruit_Name = ''
```

OR

```
Car_Name = 'Golf'
```

How can I achive that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("
  SELECT (SELECT      Car_Name
          FROM        Car_data
          WHERE       Car_Code = :carCode ) as Car_Name ,
         (SELECT  Fruit_Name
          FROM    Fruit_Data
          WHERE   Fruit_Code = :fruitCode) as Fruit_Name;
");
```

use subqueries, this should work

Comment: Is this better then 2 different queries in term of performance?

Comment: I think this answer would be faster because only need 1 connection to db, but you have to test what is the best option for you